# Mapping arrays in restkit

Tags: objective-c, arrays, mapping, restkit

In objective-c with Restkit.

I'm trying to mapping an object like this:

> {
>
> ```
> "key1":"key1",
> "key2":"key2",
> "key3":[{
>          "otherkey1":"otherkey1",
>          "otherkey2":"otherkey2"
>         },
>         {
>          "otherkey1":"otherkey1",
>          "otherkey2":"otherkey2"
>         },
>        ]
> ```
>
> }

and I'm doing something like this:

```
RKObjectManager *objMan = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient: client];

RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"key1",
                                                @"key2",
                                                @"key3"]];
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[objContainer class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];

/**/
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping1 = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping1 addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"otherkey1",
                                                @"otherkey2",
                                                ]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor1 = [RKRequestDescriptor     requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping1 objectClass:[ContainerClient class] rootKeyPath:@"key3" method:RKRequestMethodAny];

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

RKObjectMapping *objMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[objContainer class]];
[objMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                 @"key1" : @"key1",
                                                 @"key2" : @"key2",
                                                 @"key3" : @"key3",
                                                 }];

/**/
RKObjectManager *manager1 = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[manager1 addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor1];


RKObjectMapping *objMapping1 = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ContainerClient class]];
[objMapping1 addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                 @"otherkey1" : @"otherkey1",
                                                 @"otherkey2" : @"otherkey2",
                                                 }];
/**/
```

Classe ContainerClient

> @property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber* otherkey1;
>
> @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *otherkey2;

Class objContainer

> @property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber* key1;
>
> @property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber* key2;
>
> @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* key3;

have something like this code to communicate with the server when it sends the objects do not have lists and works.
how do I map a list?

Comment: You aren't creating any response descriptors. Are you sending any objects to the server or just receiving?

Comment: I send, the server fills out and returns. in other words it responds as the object I am sending

Comment: So you have request descriptors for the send. You need response descriptors for the receive. If `key3` is supposed to contain instances of `ContainerClient` then you will need a relationship mapping too.

Comment: how i do this? how i do a relationship mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up response descriptors - these are totally missing at the moment.

If `key3` is supposed to contain instances of `ContainerClient` then you will need a relationship mapping too. Do this using `addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:mapping:`.

Comment: something like this?
[objMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"key3" mapping:objMapping1];

Comment: Yes. Then a response descriptor for `objMapping`.